# .htaccess is causing internal server errors

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
# @version 7.4
# disable direct access to folders
Options -Indexes
# Follow symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE on

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# if installed in root folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# if installed in subfolder
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/<subfolder>/$1 [R=301,L]

# used to check if mod rewrite works
RewriteRule ^test-mod-rewrite$ mod-rewrite.php [NC,L]

# redirect all requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>

# 7 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 DAY - will prohibit the abuse on generating the sitemap xml file
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# using apache mod_deflate for compressing static content
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>
```

This code is supposed to generate me SEO friendly URLS, however it is giving me Internal Server errors. I have mod_rewrite installed and enabled. Please help. Find above my .htaccess file contents.

Comment: Look in the server error log to see what exactly is causing the error, and why.

Comment: /var/log/apache2/error.log is empty.

Comment: OK I narrowed it down to the following section by commenting and uncommenting out lines until it started working                                          <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

Answer (score 1):

The error was in the following two sections

```
# 7 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 DAY - will prohibit the abuse on generating the sitemap xml file
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

mod HEADER was not loaded in my Apache webserver.